# DropDownListFor with checkboxes for multiple selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is my code(MVC 5) in which I want to have a dropdownlist with the option of selecting multiple items.
Each item in the dropdownlist should have a checkbox against them. 
And when multiple items selected, comma separated list of items should appear.

I am using bootstrap multiselect.

Problem -
The dropdown is showing default item as 'None Selected'. When I click the dropdown, no drop down appears - however when the page loads, I see list of items being attached. I also confirmed that from page source.
Default item for drop down should be "Select a Group" as I am trying to bind that. However I do not know how to get rid of this default 'None Selected'.

**Model:**

```
public List<Group> Groups
{
    get
    {
        List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
        groups.Add(new Group() { Id = 1, Name = "AA" });
        groups.Add(new Group() { Id = 1, Name = "BB" });
        groups.Add(new Group() { Id = 1, Name = "CC" });
        return groups;
    }
    protected set { }
}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DefaultGroupSelectItem
{
    get
    {
        return Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem{Value = "-1", Text = "Select a Group"}, count: 1);   
    }
}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GroupSelectList
{
    get
    {
        SelectList groupSelectList = new SelectList(Groups, "Id", "Name");
        return DefaultGroupSelectItem.Concat(groupSelectList);
    }
}

[Display(Name = "Group")]
public int[] SelectedGroupIds { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult CreateTest()
{
    UserViewModel userViewModel = new UserViewModel();
    return View(userViewModel);
}
```

**View:**

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedGroupIds, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGroupIds,
                                      Model.GroupSelectList,
                                        new {@class = "multiselect", multiple = "multiple"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.SelectedGroupIds)
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('#SelectedGroupIds').multiselect();        
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone please guide what I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Html.DropDownListFor` renders a single select. Try `Html.ListBoxFor` instead.

Comment: But I want the list as a drop down.

Comment: That's simply not possible. Drop downs only support a single selection. If you need a select multiple, it renders as a listbox. Perhaps you can find a JavaScript library that can fake it to look like a dropdown, but its impossible with HTML alone.

Answer (score 0):

My bad :-(  There were two issues -

**First:**
Look at my data source that I was using for binding to DropDownList.

```
  groups.Add(new Group() { Id = 1, Name = "AA" });
  groups.Add(new Group() { Id = 1, Name = "BB" });
  groups.Add(new Group() { Id = 1, Name = "CC" });
```

All items with **Id = 1**
And that was the issue that dropdownlist click was not being handled properly.

**Second:**
Some of the jQuery and Bootstrap libraries were missing - here is the complete list of required ones:

```
    <!-- Following css and scripts required for multiselect in Html.DropDownListFor 
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    -->
```

Also, for getting rid of default 'None Selected', I had to modify variable defined in bootstrap-multiselect.js.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dropdown, follow this trick.

Bootstrap-select returns all selected values as a single comma separated string. Using JavaScript or jQuery on change method to pick this string and assign to a hidden field as its value. Now, this hidden field value is set to be selected long string. When form is submitted, the value of hidden field will also be submitted to target controller. You can use split method to separate these values and use according to your requirement.

Remember, this is just a trick, not a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like:

`@Html.DropDownList("Forms", ViewBag.Forms as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Select", multiple = "multiple" })`